# Selenium webscrapping element

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to do web scraping with Selenium (Python) from a website that has the following structure (I anonymized the html) but the GET part does not work..

I would like to retrieve the following information from the HTML :

- INFO 1
- INFO 2
- INFO 3
- TEXTE 1

Whenever I try the following code using XPATH it does not work :

code :

```
INFO_1= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/section[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/a/div[3]/div/span[1]")
```

HTML code :

```
<a href=" anonymized href " title=" **TITLE** " class="suggestion-link">
   <div>
<a href="#" style="display: inherit;"><span class="fav"></span></a></div> 
<div class="image-wrap">
   <!----> <!----> <!----> <!----> <!----> <!----> 
   <div class="carousel">
      <span id="carousel_prev_8iikolcpmwi" style="display: none;"></span> 
      <div id="carousel_o2u8ikkx7nl" class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded owl-drag">
         <div class="owl-stage-outer">
            <div class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); transition: all 0s ease 0s; width: 970px;">
               <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 323.242px;">
                  <div class="item">
                     <div class="filigrane"><img src="/images/filigrane.png"></div>
                     <div class="loaded">< anonymised.jpg" alt=" **TITLE 2**" class="img"> </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="owl-item" style="width: 323.242px;">
                  <div class="item">
                     <div class="filigrane"><img src="/images/filigrane.png"></div>
                     <div class="loaded"><img src=" anonymized.jpg" alt=" **TITLE** " class="img"> </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="owl-item" style="width: 323.242px;">
                  <div class="item">
                     <div class="filigrane"><img src="/images/filigrane.png"></div>
                     <div class="loaded"><img src=" anonymised.jpg" alt=" **TITLE** " class="img"> </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="owl-nav disabled">
            <div class="owl-prev">next</div>
            <div class="owl-next">prev</div>
         </div>
         <div class="owl-dots"><button role="button" class="owl-dot active"><span></span></button><button role="button" class="owl-dot"><span></span></button><button role="button" class="owl-dot"><span></span></button></div>
      </div>
      <span id="carousel_next_d6crxou5xy"></span>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="content-wrap">
   <div class="card-top">
      <span class="card-left uppercase"> **INFO 1**</span> 
      <span class="card-right">
         <!----> <!---->
         **INFO 2**
         <!---->
      </span>
   </div>
   <h3 class="title-wrap">**INFO 3**</h3>
   <p class=""><span class="moreup"></span> **TEXT 1**.</p>
</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the shared HTML, try below relative XPath expressions:

- To locate INFO 1:

```
//span[text()=' **INFO 1**' and @class='card-left uppercase']
```

- To locate INFO 2:

```
//span[@class='card-right']
```

- To locate INFO 3:

```
//h3[@class='title-wrap' and contains(text(),'INFO 3')]
```

- To locate TEXT 1:

```
//p[contains(text(),'TEXT 1')]
```

##### UPDATE:

Example code to store all values within a block of HTML into a variable:

```
values = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='content-wrap']")
for value in values:
    print(value.text)
```

Comment: Thank you for you anwer ! just a comment, this content (info 1, info 2, info 3, text 1) is part of a block, and there are many of these blocks in the page, they all are structured the same, how to I cope with that?

Comment: Try the code in the UPDATED answer and advise.